# python3 http server fails with broken pipe when running a systemd service

Tags: python-3.x, systemd, httpserver

I have a digital ocean server where i want to serve videos "hls files" using python3 http.server, however i am facing an error on my systemd service with broken pipe after few number of requests. i have an httpserver.py file that is helping me serve.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
# It's python3 -m http.server PORT for a CORS world

from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import sys


class CORSRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
        self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate')
        return super(CORSRequestHandler, self).end_headers()

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

host = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else '0.0.0.0'
port = int(sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 9999

print("Listening on {}:{}".format(host, port))
httpd = HTTPServer((host, port), CORSRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Here also is my systemd service.

```
[Unit]
Description=desc
After=network.target
#StartLimitInterval=400
#StartLimitBurst=3

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/media
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python3 /home/media/httpserver.py
Restart=always
#RestartSec=90

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

error am getting.

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('105.161.36.42', 2464)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 658, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 432, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 420, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 665, in do_GET
    self.copyfile(f, self.wfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/server.py", line 865, in copyfile
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, outputfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 198, in copyfileobj
    fdst_write(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 826, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```